# Add FuelPHP task to cron job using CronTab

Tags: php, cron, fuelphp

I am trying to add a FuelPHP Task as Cron job using CronTab.

I added the command as

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/project1/oil r welcomeTask
```

While doing this when i see the cron log in /var/log/cron, it show the cron job is called, but nothing happens as per the code.

But when I execute same code

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/project1/oil r welcomeTask
```

in terminal it get executed properly and gives correct result.

Can anyone suggest me the correct way to execute the FuelPHP Task using CronTab.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: I think you're forgetting the "refine" call in your code (php oil refine example "Good morning")

Comment: Sorry I missed the letter r above, thank you @StephanePaquet. I have tried using both 'refine' and 'r' its not working as it should have been.

Comment: Which crontab? And under which user is this task running (and which user are you using)? And are does this user has sufficient rights?

Comment: Crontab is a software utility and a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. 

The Crontab is using the root user. Since I am logged in the server as ROOT. The Crontab must be running using the Root User privilege. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ntuple, no you can run crontab as a standard user. But being or not being root can have an impact on your task.

Comment: Did you check FuelPhp logs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by doing

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/project1/; /usr/bin/php oil r welcomeTask
```

Comment: One point you may also have to take into account is the FUEL_ENV value. Let's say  you want to run in PRODUCTION mode you have to add the following FUEL_ENV=production before /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 2):

Thinking on Stephane comment, for a `test` environment it may work better something like:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/project1/;FUEL_ENV=test /usr/bin/php oil r welcomeTask
```

Just for the record.

Comment: I had an unrelated issue setting up tasks as cron jobs on bluehost. I ended up having to use the php-cli which you can find the path for by using ssh and typing in: `which php-cli`. And using your suggestion of putting `FUEL_ENV=production` because my database was involved. Also, setting the environment has to come **BEFORE** setting up the php file to use.